# Insert multiple rows Qt Quick Local Storage?

Tags: sql, database, qt, sqlite, qml

I'm making a mobile application in Qt Creator and I want to use Qt Quick Local Storage.

I want to add multiple rows in the initial database creation.

This is my code:

```
function init() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("test_db", "", "Local Storage test", 1000000)
    try {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id numeric, title varchar)');

            var r = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test');
            if (r.rows.length < 3) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)',
                              [1, 'One'],
                              [2, 'Two'],
                              [3, 'Three']
                            );
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating table in database: " + err)
    };
}
```

The problem is that only the first row is being inserted.

How to insert multiple rows?

Is this the right approach to insert initial data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the execution grammar separately.

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)',[1, 'One']);
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)',[2, 'Two']);
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)',[3, 'Three']);
```

or create a function to do Insert data.

```
function init() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("test_db", "", "Local Storage test", 1000000)
    try {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id numeric, title varchar)');

            var r = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test');
            if (r.rows.length < 3) {
                SaveData(tx,1,'One');
                SaveData(tx,2,'Two');
                SaveData(tx,3,'Three');
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating table in database: " + err)
    };
}


function SaveData(tx,col1, col2) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)', [col1, col2]);
}
```